# join two oracle results into single output

Tags: sql, oracle

All
I converted my two queries into tables
table1 as below:

```
SITE_ID LEGACY_PACKAGE  NEW_PACKAGE_MOVEMENT
1   CDTPMR  CDTPMRMX
1   CDTPMRNV    CDTPMRMX
1   CDTPMRU CDTPMRUMX
1   CDTPMRUNV   CDTPMRUMX
1   CONN100 CDTPMRMX
1   CONN100NVM  CDTPMRMX
1   CONNULD CONNULD
1   CONNULDNVM  CONNULD
1   ESSENTIALS  SIM3PKG
1   ESSENTLNVM  CDTESS
1   PHNE PREFR  CDTPMRMX
```

and table 2 as below:

```
SITE_ID PACKAGE_CODE    SERVICE_RATE
1   CDTESSU 0
1   CDTESSU 0
1   CDTESSU 0
1   CDTESSU 7.93
1   CDTESSU 12.99
1   CDTESSU -7.93
1   CDTESSU 8.99
1   CDTESSU 12.99
1   CDTESSU 0
1   CDTESSU 8.99
1   CDTESSU -5.99
1   CDTESSU 15.99
1   CDTESSU 0
1   CDTESSU 0
1   CDTESSU -5.99
```

my new output should be like

```
SITE_ID LEGACY_PACKAGE service_rate1    NEW_PACKAGE_MOVEMENT service_rate2
```

by comparing legacy_package (table1) with package_code (table2) to service_rate1

```
 by comparing NEW_PACKAGE_MOVEMENT (table1) with package_code (table2) to service_rate2

I am trying different ways in oracle sql, but finding it harder.
is there any clue how to achieve this?
```

Comment: is this your join condition LEGACY_PACKAGE=PACKAGE_CODE?

Comment: yes to get service_rate1. i need to compare new_package_movement with package_code to service_rate2.

Comment: whats the difference between service_rate1 and service_rate2

Comment: legacy_package is old package and its rate.

Comment: NEW_PACKAGE_MOVEMENT is new package and again to find the service rate from table 2. table 2 contain both old and new package code with their rate

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this..(untested)

```
    select 
    t1.site_id,t1.legacy_package,
    (case when t1.legacy_package=t2.package_code 
          then t2.service_rate else null end) as service_rate1,
    t1.new_package_movement,
    (case when t1.new_package_movement=t2.package_code
    then t2.service_rate else null end) as service_rate2
    from table1 t1 join 
    table t2 where t1.site_id=t2.site_id and 
   ((t1.legacy_package=t2.package_code) or (t2.new_package_movement=t2.package_code))
```

Comment: can i try inner query fetch 2nd service_rate1 like

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT T1.site_id,
  T1.LEGACY_PACKAGE AS "From ICOMS Package cd",
  T2.SERVICE_RATE,
  T1.NEW_PACKAGE_MOVEMENT AS "To ICOMS Package cd" ,
    (SELECT T2.SERVICE_RATE AS SERVICE_RATE_NEW
  FROM table1 T1
  INNER JOIN table2 T2
  ON T1.site_id              =T2.SITE_ID
  AND T1.NEW_PACKAGE_MOVEMENT=T2.PACKAGE_CODE
  )
FROM table1 T1
INNER JOIN table2 T2
ON T1.site_id        =T2.SITE_ID
AND T1.LEGACY_PACKAGE=T2.PACKAGE_CODE
ORDER BY T1.site_id ,T1.LEGACY_PACKAGE

Comment: yes, your version is good. i tried already. but i want to use inner query as provided above. but i am gettting ORA-0142 (getting more than one row in the inner query)

Comment: your inner query wont work because  `(SELECT T2.SERVICE_RATE AS SERVICE_RATE_NEW
            FROM table1 T1
                 INNER JOIN table2 T2
                    ON     T1.site_id = T2.SITE_ID
                       AND T1.NEW_PACKAGE_MOVEMENT = T2.PACKAGE_CODE)` is retrieving more than one row